# Are injective functions necessarily defined on their entire domain?

Tags: functions

According to wikipedia, a function $f$ with domain $X$ is injective iff
$$\forall a,b\in X(f(a)=f(b) \rightarrow a=b)$$
It doesn't say anything about whether or not $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ have to be defined. In practice it wouldn't really make sense to define a function on, say $\mathbb{R}$ if the domain can be more specific, like $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$. Unless you're defining a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ as the domain of some function or something. Anyway, I just need to know whether or not this is included in the definition for injectivity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function is always defined for the entirety of its domain. Otherwise it is called a *partial function*. Partial functions can be injective, too.

Comment: It might be worth  mentioning that "A function is always defined for the entirety of its domain" is not some constraint arbitrarily imposed on functions to avoid demotion to "partial"; rather, it is simply the definition of "domain".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because of the definition of **domain**. When we say that a function has a domain $X$, we mean that it assigns a value to every point in the set $X$. So---if a function $f$ has a domain $X$, then for every $a,b\in X$, $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are necessarily defined.

You might be thinking of a function like $g(x) = 1/x$, which is not defined at the point $x=0$. In fact this means that the domain of $g$ can't be all of $\mathbb{R}$, but must be some smaller set like $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$.

Or you might be thinking of the *codomain* of a function. A function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ *must* assign a value to every point in $X$, because $X$ is its domain.  But the function doesn't need to map something onto every point $y\in Y$. That's a difference between how domains and codomains are defined.

So for example the function $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $h(x) = e^x$ can legally have $\mathbb{R}$ as its codomain, even though the output of $e^x$ is never negative.

Answer (score 0):

The usual definition of a function is that it is defined on its entire domain.  Sometimes the domain is defined as the set of values that the function is defined on.  In either case you can count on $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ being defined.